# ColdFusion 11 with websockets can't publish a message

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, websocket

I'm trying to get websockets working with ColdFusion. I am unable to send or receive messages and I am at a loss as to why. Am I missing something? Do I need to have any other programs installed? I am using Adobe ColdFusion Builder 3 Developer Edition.

Here is the code I am attempting to use.

Websocket.cfm

```
<cfwebsocket name="mycfwebsocketobject"  onmessage="MessageHandler" subscribeto="stocks" > 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

   function MessageHandler(message) 
   { 
        alert(message.data);

   } 

   function publishstock()
   {    
        mycfwebsocketobject.Publish('stocks', 'I sent a message!');
   }
   setInterval('publishstock()',1000);
</script>
```

Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cfset this.name="Websocket">
    <cfset this.wschannels=[{name="stocks"}]>

</cfcomponent>
```

My goal is to get the MessageHandler function to trigger without explicitly calling it. I have no idea what is wrong and I have matched my code up perfectly with many examples on the web. I have been unsuccessful in both Chrome and Firefox.

I think that the real problem might have something to do with my machine. I found a demo online that worked perfectly, but when I downloaded the source it no longer worked. Is there a way to test for this?

Resources: 
           https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ys6BGrYJhNg
           http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/html5-websockets-coldfusion-pt1.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `setInterval('publishstock()',1000);`

Should be:

`setInterval(function(){publishstock();},1000);`

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that publishstock() actually does get hit. It is the publish call inside that fails to send a message. I think that the real problem might have something to do with my machine. I found a demo online that worked perfectly, but when I downloaded the source, it no longer worked. Thanks for the response anyway.